# error: passing 'float [4]' to parameter of incompatible type 'float'

Tags: c, cs50

I have to create a function called print_array that takes two parameters: a float array and an integer (denoting the length of the array). The function should print the entire array of floats to a precision of two decimals. E.g.,

```
float a[] = {1.555, 3, 1.645, 178};
print_array(a, 4);
```

It should give:

```
1.55, 3.00, 1.64, 178.00
```

My code goes as follows (a bit messy):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int times_two(int a);
void print_int(int a);
int half(int a);
void print_float(float a);
void max(float a);
float average(float a);
void print_array(float a, int b);


int main (void)
{
    int z = get_int("First Value for exercise 3? ");
    int g = get_int("Second Value for exercise 3? ");
    int max_value_1 = get_int("First Value (max) for exercise 4? ");
    int max_value_2 = get_int("Second Value (max for exercise 4? ");
    int x = 2;
    int y = half(x);
    float q = average(z + g);
    print_int(y);
    print_float(2.7444);
    print_float(q);
    if(max_value_1 > max_value_2 || max_value_1 == max_value_2)
    {
        max(max_value_1);
    }
    else
    {
        max(max_value_2);
    }
    float a[] = {1.555, 3, 1.645, 178};
    print_array(a, 4);
}
float average(float a)
{
    return a / 2;
}

int times_two(int a)
{
    return a * 2;
}

int half(int a)
{
    return a / 2;
}

void print_int(int a)
{
    printf("Value Exercise 1 = %i\n", a);
}

void print_float(float a)
{
    printf("Value Exercise 2/3 = %.2f\n", a);
}

void max(float a)
{
    printf("Value Exercise 4 = %.2f\n", a);
}

void print_array(float a, int b)
{
    printf("Value Exercise 4 = %.2f\n", a);
}
```

For some other reason I get this error and really don't know how to fix them as I am new to ''functions'':

```
functions.c:37:17: error: passing 'float [4]' to parameter of incompatible type 'float'
    print_array(a, 4);
                ^
functions.c:13:24: note: passing argument to parameter 'a' here
void print_array(float a, int b);
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Re "*I have to create a function called print_array that takes two parameters: a float array and an integer*", 1. That's not what you did. Your function takes a `float` and an `int`. 2. In fact, it's not possible to have a float array parameter. The function should take a pointer to a `float` (the first of the array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    void print_array(float a, int b);
```

This line says that `print_array`'s first parameter is a `float`.

```
    float a[] = {1.555, 3, 1.645, 178};
    print_array(a, 4);
```

This line passes an array as the first parameter to `print_array`. This is inconsistent with the line shown previously that says the first parameter is a `float`.

This is precisely what the error is telling you.

Your first step in fixing this would be to change this:

```
    void print_array(float a, int b);
```

To something like:

```
    void print_array(float a[], int b);
```

or

```
    void print_array(float *a, int b);
```

Comment: I would suggest `size_t` instead of `int`

Comment: @0___________, That would be better, but gotta do what the assignment asks